# how to handle errors such as Value Error Python

Tags: python, tkinter, calculator, calculation

when a user clicks on the enter button or runs the code without entering an input an error occurs saying ValueError. How can I debug this so that when the user does this a message appears saying enter a valid input.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
#======================================================================
notebook = ttk.Notebook(root)

frame1 = ttk.Frame(notebook)
notebook.add(frame1, text='Length')
notebook.pack(expand=1, fill="both")

#======================================================================
def Length_converter(*args):
    v = float(entry.get())
    metre_dict = dict(mm= 0.001, cm= 0.01, m= 1, km= 1000, Inches= 0.0254, Feet= 0.3048, Yards= 0.9144, Miles= 1609.344)
    M = v * metre_dict[var1.get()]
    k = M / metre_dict[var2.get()]
    label['text']=k
#======================================================================
#======================= ===============================================
entry = Entry(frame1)
entry.grid(row=0, column=0)

label = Label(frame1, relief='groove', width=20, text='')
label.grid(row=0, column=3)

options1 = ['Unit', 'mm', 'cm', 'm', 'km', 'Inches', 'Feet', 'Yards', 'Miles']

var1 = tk.StringVar(frame1)
var1.set(options1[0])

dropdown1 = tk.OptionMenu(frame1, var1, options1[1], options1[2], options1[3], options1[4], options1[5], options1[6], options1[7], options1[8])
dropdown1.grid(row=1, column=0)

var2 = tk.StringVar(frame1)
var2.set(options1[0])

dropdown2 = tk.OptionMenu(frame1, var2, options1[1], options1[2], options1[3], options1[4], options1[5], options1[6], options1[7], options1[8])
dropdown2.grid(row=1, column=3)

equal_button = Button(frame1, text='=', command=Length_converter) 
equal_button.grid(row=1, column=5)
#======================================================================
root.mainloop
```

Comment: Check if the input string (`temp_entry.get()`) is empty or not?

Comment: that's the problem when the ( temp_entry.get() ) is empty an error occurs when there is nothing there I want an error message to appear saying enter a valid input

Comment: ***You*** have to check if it's empty or not, *before* you use the string. The `if` and `else` statements are useful to know for this.

Comment: I updated the code, when the variable v in the length converter function is not a float an error occurs. how do i make it so that when the variable v is empty a message saying enter valid input appears.

Comment: The problem is the `float` conversion, that will cause the failure. Like I said, you have to check the *string*, and you have you check it *before* you even use it anywhere.

Comment: `if not temp_entry.get(): print("Enter a valid input.")`

Answer (score 0):

For This You Need TO Import Tkinter Message Box With:

```
From tkinter import messagebox
```

#### Code:

```
Try:
## Code That Gets Users Entry
Except ValueError:
    messagebox.showinfo('Error', message='Enter A Valid Input')
```